# Sql Server Date Format DD-Mon-YY

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datetime-format

We're working to migrate our app from Oracle 11 to SQL Server 2014. There are lot of places in our Java code that expects the date in `DD-Mon-YY` format. I couldn't find an option with convert or any other built-in function to do this with out stuffing "-" in to the converted string.

Today we are using something like

```
upper((((CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Dt_Column, 113), 3, 1, '-'), 7, 3, '-'),1,18))
```

We are using this for multiple columns in the same view that loads a few hundred thousand rows, I'm suspecting it might affect our performance. Any inputs/thoughts will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find an option to convert with getDate().

Comment: Thanks to all the inputs here. This is the closest I could arrive, with the inputs I received: `SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-') +' '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 108);` Performance is still poor 25% poorer than my original query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will achieve the desired affect:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Dt_Column, 106), ' ', '-')
```

Style `106` for `CONVERT` provides the date in the format `dd mon yyyy`, which you may then simply replace the spaces with the dash.

**Update**

Based on the additional information that the format should also include time, you could try using `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

One thing to keep in mind is that `FORMAT` relies on the CLR, so you would need to gauge the performance impact. Although, with your dataset a single call to `FORMAT` could be equivalent or potentially perform better than multiple native function calls.

In either case, if you find the impact of obtaining the date in the correct format is too great, you could use a persisted computed column in SQL Server to hold the formatted date. If you did not want to rename the column reference in your Java code, you could rename the source column and name the new computed column the original name of the source column.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql.

> [PERSISTED] will physically store the computed values in the table, and update the values when any other columns on which the computed column depends are updated

Comment: Thanks Joey, this is definitely really close to what I need. Just need to find a way to include the timestamp to this. Checking for options now.

Comment: @rsreji I updated my answer with some additional information on how you can achieve including the timestamp along with the output (I wasn't clear on that part based on the `DD-Mon-YYYY` example given in your question). Additionally, I provided some info on `PERSISTED` computed columns, which may help with any performance concerns. The computed column would be stored on the table, then referenced in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Using Joey's answer as a starting point and combining this with the information from the ***Date and Time Styles*** section in the learn.microsoft.com **CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)** page, the CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @Value, 6) emits the two digit year you were looking for.

```
DECLARE     @Now AS DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT          @Now AS '@Now'
            ,   REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @Now, 6), ' ', '-') AS 'Abbr@Now'

/***********************************************************************

    Results:

        @Now                    Abbr@Now
        ----------------------- ---------
        2017-12-22 10:08:33.443 22-Dec-17

        (1 row(s) affected)

 ***********************************************************************/
```

Additional DATETIME formatting using CONVERT() can be found at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

I hope this was of help.